# Cant get variable from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, md5

I need to get some data from MySQL DB (it certainly exists) to proceed and analyse it. So, what I have in my code:

```
  if (count($errors) == 0)  
$password = md5($password); 
$query = "SELECT username, password, email FROM trackowners WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"; 
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  ///////////
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  header('location: index.php');
}else {
  array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
} }
```

Then I am trying to use variables $_SESSION['username'] and email one:

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
    <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong> // Here are your profile settings.</p>

    <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
<?php endif ?>

  <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
  <p>Your e-mail<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></strong> //</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

And here I am getting username variable but I cant get anything from email variable. Whats the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Your problem is solved by asking yourself one simple question: *Where in your code do you assign a value to `$email`?* The answer is provided by any basic tutorial on using a database with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I have a LOT of question about your code (do not use MD5 for password hashing, instead use [PHP build in hashing method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)). But to continue on the post of @Nicolas

**Edited to follow on Jay Blanchard advice**

```
// Make sure your session is started
session_start();    

if (count($errors) == 0){
    // Make sure to store your passwords with the same function
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT ); 
    // Prepare your query with placeholders
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username, password, email FROM trackowners WHERE username=? AND password=?');
    // Execute your query
    if($query->execute(array($username, $password)))
    {
        // Loop through result set
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";     
        }
        header('location: index.php');  
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination"); 
    }
}
```

Also as mentioned by @Nicolas read up on [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent sql injections.

Comment: Yes-yes, I know about this ecnryption techinques. I am not trying to do it right now, because I do not have enough knowledge. About this code: now I cant access index.php page because of "wrong username combination" error

Comment: That is the whole purpose i assume? Not reaching one page when the username and/or password are incorrect?

Comment: No, it was working quite okay (about not accessing). On index.php I want to show "email" variable. By the way, I am not able to access the page even if I am using correct combination

Comment: What error does PHP return? Did you create a PDO object: `$pdo = @new PDO('mysql:host=host_name;dbname=' . Config::database_name;charset=utf8', database_user, database_password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));`

Comment: I am getting an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/begosolu/public_html/moofta/php/server.php on line 77

Comment: Yeah you just copied the code without creating an PDO object. Please read up on how to use pdo https://phpdelusions.net/pdo. Also refer to my previous comment which basically gives the answer.